# Adding a closing tag to the DOM before an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm needing to insert a closing tag before an element in the DOM. But jQuery doesn't like the idea of inserting what it believes to be malformed markup.

To provide a little context, I'm needing to do it this way because I am unable to alter the code displayed by the Wordpress the_content() function. All I'm doing is closing a wrapper div, which I will open again after the next element, so there won't actually be any malformed code.

I suppose I'm looking for something similar to the following:

```
$('</div><!-- Close Mobile Wrapper -->').insertBefore('.right-col');
```

But the above renders nothing in the source. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Add it as innerHTML, not as an element.

Comment: you can't create incomplete dom elements, even if you intend to make them complete later.

Comment: The dom doesn't have malformed html in it, if it was built from malformed html you really cant do much about that, you could fix the html at the source but thats about it.

Comment: Right. Just remembered. The browser will probably take that unclosed div and close it for you.

Comment: You got: <div> someContent  <div class="right-col"></div> </div>
and you want it to be
<div>someContent</div>
<div class="right-col">content2</div>

    am I right?

Comment: @EranH.That's exactly what I'm after.

Comment: Just take $('.right-col'), remove it from the DOM, and insert it after.

Something like this: var $parent = $('.right-col').parent(); $('.right-col').remove().after($parent);

Comment: @EranH.That's an option I looked at, but it fails because it's unable to retrieve the content originally intended for that div from the Wordpress function.

Comment: By what your'e saying your original try to write .insertBefore('.right-col') will not work either

Comment: @EranH. It should do, because your method removes the element and its contents, which will need to be added in again later, which I can't do obviously. My sought method simply closes out the containing div, but the content is still there. I then just open up the containing div when I'm done.

Comment: "which I can't do obviously" why not? Taking a div from the DOM and replacing it should work for most cases. Like in the code example I wrote earlier

Comment: @EranH. The element can be added in sure, but the contents within it cannot then be fetched dynamically using the wordpress the_content() function. Or atleast, not starting from where I need it to. If I was working with static code, Or at least code I have any control over, your suggestion would be perfect. It just doesn't work in this case.

Comment: So even if your initial solution would work you would still be stuck with the same problem, no?